# ratio between the area of square $wxyz$ and the area of square $ abcd$ equal?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, centroid

> $ABCD$ is a square  and $H$ is an interior point, which divides  it for four triangles. If  $W$, $X,$ $Y$ and $Z$  are  the centroids of triangles $AHD$, $AHB$, $BHC$ and  $CHD$  respectively ,
>     then what is  the ratio between the area of the **square  $WXYZ$** and the area of the **square  $ABCD$** ?

[image]

Can anyone provide me a hint or a help to go  ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Think of this as a 3D problem, where $ABCDH$ is a square pyramid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$XW=YZ=\frac{1}{3}BD$, $XY=WZ=\frac{1}{3}AC$ and $XYZW$ is square.

Thus, the ratio is $\frac{2}{9}$ because $S_{ABCD}=\frac{1}{2}AC\cdot BD$ and
$$\frac{S_{XYZW}}{S_{ABCD}}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}AC\cdot\frac{1}{3}BD}{\frac{1}{2}AC\cdot BD}=\frac{2}{9}$$

For example, let $M$ is a midpoint of $BH$.

Hence, $$\frac{XY}{AC}=\frac{MY}{MC}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: but  the answer  is $2/9$

Comment: @prayer smith I fixed. See now, please.

Comment: please have another look , i add a graph of the problem

Comment: @prayer smith Yes it works. Just $\Delta MAC\sim\Delta XMY$. What is your question?

Comment: @prayer smith I posted an explanation for $XY=\frac{1}{3}AC$. Ask your question. The rest is the same.

Comment: i got it , thank you very much,  genius

Comment: @prayer smith You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Draw the point on $AH$ that's closer to $A$ than $H$ in a 1:2 ratio. Call this $A'$. Repeat for $B$, $C$, and $D$. Show that $A'B'C'D'$ is another square, and that each vertex of $WXYZ$ is the midpoint of an edge of $A'B'C'D'$. Conclude that $WXYZ$ has half the area as $A'B'C'D'$.

Note, by the way, that there's no reason to assume that $H$ is coplanar with $ABCD$. In fact, it feels easier to visualize this problem if you assume it's not, making $ABCDH$ a square prism.